# Hive MetaStore Configuration

Tags: hive

I have changed the Hive Metastore from Derby to SQL as given in this specification.
https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/CDHDOC/Hive+Installation

Please tell me how can I ensure whether it is changed to SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the metastore schema in your MySQL database. 
Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM TBLS;
```

on your MySQL database should you the names of your Hive tables.

Add a new table and verify that the above query returns updated results.